# recreating gulp config on webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp

Right now really need help to understand webpack, although I'm trying so much, im still not understand how I can use webpack as a task runner rather than just module bundler. This is a learning process, so please lets not discuss of why gulp/webpack is better than other for this kind of job.

You see the code is actually pretty simple, the idea is to crawl every htmlfile based on a template that injected with a variable from css and js with the same name. This gulpfile is what I use in order to create Polymerjs Html File.

Is there any way I could convert this into Webpack specific build tools? Where should I put the information to crawl the folder in the webpack? Should I put it into index.js?

I understand the concept of using a specific entry files for Webpack, but when facing this kind of usecase, what should I do?

```
gulp.task('templates', function() {
// crawl folder pathToFolder
    readdir(pathToFolder, ['*.scss', '*.js', '*.json'], function(err, files) {
        // loop every file founds
        files.forEach(function(file) {
            let data = file.substr(10);
            // make sure the path is correct when used on windows device.
            data = data.replace(String.fromCharCode(92), String.fromCharCode(47));
            let index = data.lastIndexOf('/');
            let path = data.substr(0, index);
            let scss = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) + '.scss';
            let js = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) + '.js';
            let json = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.')) + '.json';
            // process all files into their respective loader and squash it into one variable to use on the template.
            let process = {
                css: '',
                form: '',
                js: '',
                json: '',
            };
            if (fs.existsSync(scss)) {
                process = Object.assign(process, {
                    css: sass.compiler.renderSync({
                        file: scss,
                    }).css,
                });
            }
            if (fs.existsSync(js)) {
                process = Object.assign(process, {
                    js: fs.readFileSync(js, 'utf8'),
                });
            }
            if (fs.existsSync(json)) {
                let x = gulp.src('./ramen-renderer.html')
                    .pipe(template({
                        json: json,
                    }));
                process = Object.assign(process, {
                    json: x,
                });
                // jsonProcess = Object.assign(jsonProcess, {json: fs.readFileSync(json, "utf8")});
            }
            // render the final html path with gulp-template
            return gulp.src(file)
                .pipe(template(process))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('src/' + path));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: use the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module instead of these string replacements for OS-agnostic path manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

webpack is not a task runner but a module bundler. That means you need another way to run tasks. The most common way to do this is to use NPM for this. You define your tasks in your package.json under the scripts section.